# Import Excel to Datagridview -

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I want to Import Excel to `Datagridview` and after search found this: [Import Excel to Datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293643/import-excel-to-datagridview)

```
stirng file = "c:\myFile.xlsx";
DataGridView dgvIM;

private void Import()
        {
            String name = "Items";
            String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                            file +
                            ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';";

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);
            con.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
            System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dgvIM.DataSource = data;
        }
```

And received this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: 'Items$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.
```

What does it mean ?

Comment: The name of the table should be the exact name of a sheet in excel. Check if you have a sheet named `Items`

Comment: That's a different question, by the way, if this was just a typo then I suggest to delete this question