# I cant import excel to datagridview

Tags: c#, excel

I simply tried to take data from excel and show them in excel.When I click the button the data in excel will be listed in datagridview.

My codes:

```
private void btn_load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
                System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
                MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\kitap.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'");
                MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
                MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
                DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
                MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
                MyConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Error:

[image: Error When I tried to import]

Comment: have you checked that sheet1 exists in your excel workbook?

Comment: yes I have checked and I created one more excel file and still error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String name = "sheet1";
        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                        "C:\\Sample.xlsx" + 
                        ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);
        con.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);
        grid_items.DataSource = data;
    }
```

Comment: Copy :P  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293643/import-excel-to-datagridview

Comment: @Nalaka Its just a basic code that every one follows while writing code (names especially).. I cant help if some one write the same code before me... Do you follow any other convention while writing this pic of code then do let me Know.. i will also Learn From U.. :)