# Load Excel table into already initialized DataGridView in c# WinForms

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to append Excel table data into DataGridView (**dgvInitial**). At the beginning I'm initializing DGV by

```
private void DataForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int column = 100;
        int rows = 1000;

        dgvInitial.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        for (int i = 1; i <= column; i++)
        {
            dgvInitial.Columns.Add("Col_" + i, "Col_" + i);
            dgvInitial.Columns[i - 1].FillWeight = 1;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            dgvInitial.Rows.Add();

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgvInitial.Columns)
        {
            col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        }
    }
```

and in **loadToolStripMenuItem_Click** event I'm trying to append excel table into dgv (source code used from another stackoverflow task but the question is very different)

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
        System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
        MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Sample.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
        MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com");
        DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
        dgvInitial.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
        MyConnection.Close();
```

but it's only reducing count of rows in dgv and I cannot see any data. When I comment everything in DataForm_Load event so it is working fine.

Please, do you have any idea, how can solve this issue? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Excel to Datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293643/import-excel-to-datagridview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Try this format for Connection String,**

```
     string Connectionstr = "";      
      string filePath ="C:\Sample.xlsx";
      string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower();

      if (fileExtension == ".xls")
      Connectionstr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'";
      if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
      Connectionstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'";
        MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(Connectionstr);
        MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
       MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com");
        DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
       MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
       dgvInitial.Columns.Clear();
       dgvInitial.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
       dgvInitial.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
        MyConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!! Works great.