# Importing data from Excel to Visual studio dataGridView. Get this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I am importing excel data to dataGridView from this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293643/import-excel-to-datagridview). But I get error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

```
        String name = "Sheet1";
        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                        file +
                        ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);
        con.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);
        dgvIM.DataSource = data;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: On which line do you get that exception?

Comment: On the last line  dgvIM.DataSource = data;

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code? Or at least where you are calling this from.

Comment: Here I call it:  private void toolStripMenuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
          
            Import();
        }

Comment: I have no idea how you managed to set your `DataGridView` to null...  if you click on `dgvIM` and press F12 (or right click -> Go to definition) where does it take you? To a `designer.cs` file? Can you show that code snippet?

Comment: it takes me to its definition: DataGridView dgvIM;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value of dgvIM when debugging. It's probably null;

Comment: If it is null then how to give it a value?

Comment: If it is null then how to give it a value?

Comment: It should be an instance of the datagridview you are trying to fill. So it should be name of the datagridview  (design mode)