# Import excel sheet to a datagrideview

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to use this code [Used Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293643/import-excel-to-datagridview) to import an excel sheet to data grideview but this exception is fired and i do not know what is the main probelm.

[image: Exception]

I am trying some solutions like change the active solution platform from anyone to x86 but it does not work

Does the excel file version is important Excel 2010 , Excel 2013 ?

**update:**
I installed Microsoft Office Access database engine from this [Site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734), and the last exception is disappeared but this new exception is fired

[image: Exception#2]

This is the used code:

```
public void importfromexcel()
    {
        string SheetPath = @"E:\students.xlsx";
        string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + SheetPath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;';";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + SheetPath + "$]", con);
        System.Data.DataTable data = new System.Data.DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }
```

Is there any problem in this code ??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last error appears fairly straightforward, either you do not have permission to the file OR the file is already open. I am guessing it may still be open if you have been having problems. Have you checked the Task Manager to see if any lingering Access processes are still running?

Comment: @JohnG Yes, i have already checked it and there are not any lingering Access processes are still running !

Comment: What about Excel... as it appears you are opening an Excel file.

Comment: This exception is disappeared when i re-start visual studio but my current exception is :          Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 107.

Comment: You should take a closer look at the line…`OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + SheetPath + "$]", con);` … it looks like you are trying to get a “sheet” from the file name “E:\students.xlsx”?...  the sheet name is “E:\students.xlsx”?

Comment: i changed the SheetPath  with the file name , but  still not working !

Comment: Its not looking for a (file) "Workbook" name... its looking for a "Worksheet" name in the workbook.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176375/discussion-between-nemo-and-johng).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below with some small changes… it works as expected.

```
string WorkBookPath = @"D:\Test\Book1.xlsx";  //@"E:\students.xlsx";
string SheetName = "Sheet1$"; // <--- this is the name of the WORKSHEET in the workBOOK
string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + WorkBookPath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr)) {
  OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + SheetName + "]", con);
  DataTable data = new DataTable();
  sda.Fill(data);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
}
```