# Is there any way to export data from DataGridView to an Excel spreadsheet continously?

Tags: excel, vb.net, user-interface

So I am writing a Graphical User Interface in VB.NET which allows the user to read data from an Arduino Uno's Serial Monitor. The problem is that I can only export data at the end of the measurment with the following code:

```
Private Sub Button_Save_To_Excel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Save_To_Excel.Click

        Button_Save_To_Excel.Height = 37
        Button_Save_To_Excel.Text = "Please Wait..."
        Button_Save_To_Excel.Enabled = False
        Button_Start_Recording.Enabled = False
        ProgressBar_Save_To_Excel.Visible = True
        ProgressBar_Save_To_Excel.Value = 1

        Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer

        ProgressBar_Save_To_Excel.Value = 3

        xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1)

        ProgressBar_Save_To_Excel.Value = 5

        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
            For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                For k As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, k) = DataGridView1.Columns(k - 1).HeaderText
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
                Next
            Next
        Next

        ProgressBar_Save_To_Excel.Value = 8

        Dim savePath As String = Nothing
        Using sd As New SaveFileDialog
            With sd
                .RestoreDirectory = True
                .Filter = "Excel XLS Files(*.xls)|*.xls|Excel Macro Embedded Files(*.xlsm)|*.xlsm|Excel XLSX Files(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
                .FilterIndex = 3
                If .ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                    savePath = .FileName
                End If
            End With
        End Using

        If savePath IsNot Nothing AndAlso savePath.Trim <> "" Then
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(savePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue)
        End If

        xlWorkBook.Close(True, misValue, misValue)
        xlApp.Quit()

        ProgressBar_Save_To_Excel.Value = 10

        MsgBox("Successfully saved" & vbCrLf & "Files are saved at : " & savePath, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Information")

        ProgressBar_Save_To_Excel.Visible = False

        Process.Start(savePath)

        Button_Save_To_Excel.Height = 50
        Button_Save_To_Excel.Text = "Save To MS Excel"
        Button_Save_To_Excel.Enabled = True
        Button_Start_Recording.Enabled = True


    End Sub
```

Is there any way to modify the code so I could continously overwrite the existing Excel file with the new data arriving from the serial monitor? I've tried to use loops for this without any success.

The GUI would be used as a Data Aquisition System, which would register data for long hours or even days. For this reason I can't afford to only export data after the end of the measurment. If a power outage occures all the measurment data will be lost.

Comment: Well, you can log the data to a file and *take a snapshot* of the data on demand, exporting it to Excel. So you'll both preserve the data and have means to view it in the Excel UI without much hassle.

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need to use, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application when the sole purpose it to create excel file. There are better libraries for that
2. You can use Excel via ADO.net and all operations can be done in a regular ADO.net way, like if it was a DB Table. Here is example https://stackoverflow.com/a/16296106/1704458
3. And the key here - use data bindings. Then you don't add rows to the grid but add them to the datasource object - datatable/dataview. Set UPDDATE command on DataAdupter and wire a trigger to call `dataAdapter.Update`.

And you will not need to press the button